# Service timed out using geocoders API in Geopy

Tags: python-2.7, geopy

I found this code online but it is not working for me:

```
from geopy import geocoders

    g = geocoders.GeoNames(username="myusersname")
    (place, point) = g.geocode("Palo Alto, CA 94306")
    print place

    print point


    (new_place,new_point) = g.reverse(point)
    print new_place

    print new_point
```

Errors out with:

```
   raise GeocoderTimedOut('Service timed out')
geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out
```